# Bigtable scan of 130 million rows throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not started

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, hbase-client

Trying to scan Bigtable which has 130 million rows using the HBase java client. After a few hours into the scan, it throws:

```
INFO com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation - Retrying failed call. Failure #1, got: Status{code=DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, description=Error while reading table '', cause=null} on channel 5.
```

There were a few such exceptions from which the retry recovered but eventually results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not started
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:507)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.request(ClientCallImpl.java:367)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall$SimpleForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:44)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall$SimpleForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:44)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor$1.request(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:146)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall$SimpleForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:44)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.Watchdog$WatchedCall.request(Watchdog.java:198)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.RetryingReadRowsOperation$CallToStreamObserverAdapter.request(RetryingReadRowsOperation.java:90)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:78)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:35)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.read.BigtableResultScannerAdapter$1.next(BigtableResultScannerAdapter.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner$1.hasNext(ResultScanner.java:53)
```

Comment: This seems like it might be a bug in the retry logic. Can you open an issue on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues and assign it to igorbernstein2? Please include a list of your dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @IgorBernstein. Opened the issue but was unable to assign it to you. Here is the link - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/2020

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue. I'll work on reproducing and fixing it this week

Comment: Thanks for the update. There is one more minor bug which we opened as well - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update: both of these issues were fixed in version 1.9.0